# When i do my angular app ng build, routers dont work

Tags: angular

I opened an angular file in normal basic settings. Then I did the coding on it. I also added routing to it. Now I am trying to upload my file to a website called [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). When I say ng build, when I open the dist file on both the live server and the original server, it does not accept the routing parts. It gives me this error Cannot GET /marketplace. How do i need to solve this problem.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:"", component:HomeComponentComponent},
  {path:"home", component: HomeComponentComponent},
  {path: 'marketplace', component:MarketplaceComponent},
  {path:"mycollection", component:MycollectionComponent}
]
```

Comment: Did you import MarketplaceComponent in your app.module?

Comment: Yeah i import it. Actually its working on localhost. But when i do ng build. It gives error

Answer (score 0):

When pushing to a server and not using ng serve you usually have to configure the server to do rewriting. See the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

They give several examples including apache, iis, firebase, etc...